# C# SQL login - Adding information fail

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, string

Ok so I have a string issue. Im not sure if its simple and ive just been stareing at it for ages and come to nothing, or it's something I can't avoid?

So I am trying to login to an SQL server using C#. Once the login box shows up I pass the username and password to a connection class and the login is Sucessful.

```
    public void login(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sqlconnect sql = new sqlconnect();

        sql.us = textBox1.Text;
        sql.pas = textBox2.Text;
            try
            {
                sql.GetSqlConnection();
                sql.myConnection.Open();
                label3.Text = "Connected";
                this.Hide();
                fronthyb.Show();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

**So below is my connection class:**

```
    public class sqlconnect
{
    public SqlConnection myConnection { get; set; }
    public String us;
    public String pas;
    Settings1 set = new Settings1();


    public SqlConnection GetSqlConnection()
    {
        if (myConnection == null)
            myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id="+(us)+"; password="+(pas)+";server="+(set.SelectServer)+";Trusted_Connection="+(set.SelectContype)+";database="+(set.SelectDataBase)+"; connection timeout="+(set.Condrop)+"");

        return myConnection;
    }


}
```

**The issue now arrises when I attempt to add information to the database:**

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            sql.GetSqlConnection();

            SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("insert into dbo.Employee(FirstName, LastName, DoB, UserName, Email, Role, JobTitle, MemberOf) values (@FirstName, @LastName, @DoB, @UserName, @Email, @Role, @JobTitle, @MemberOf)", sql.myConnection);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", textBox2.Text);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", textBox3.Text);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DoB", textBox5.Text);
            sql.myConnection.Open();
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sql.myConnection.Close();
            this.Close();
```

I havnt got any catches yet since its still in development but the program crashes and basically says the User is not allowed. I tested the strings in the connection classes and when i call them after I have logged in it returns nothing. So it seems like its being replaced with "null" at somepoint? Im not sure. Anyone see anything obvious? Sorry for the long question. Thank you.

Comment: Without an Exception its hard to tell what the issue is, also you havent provided all of the insert parameters. Try avoid using try/catch and especially with MessageBox in the catch part.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `sql` that you use in the `login` method is local to that method.

That means that the object that you create there is not reachable outside the method, and whatever variable named `sql` that you use in the `button1_Click` method is not the same as in the `login` method, and doesn't have the user name and password that was set there.

Answer (score 1):

appears to be a scoping issue. In your login handler, you define a local variable of type SqlConnect. If you have a global variable named "sql" as it appears is being referenced in button1_Click handler, it won't have username/password properties set as it's a different instance.